# Angular 2 with Kendo - Incorrect URL when running the app

Tags: angularjs, kendo-ui

I am using Visual Studio 2017 Community for a Angular 2 app, and am trying to use Kendo UI. I have the following app.module.ts, and have added the ButtonsModule at the location specified in the import statement.

```
import { NgModule }      from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

// Kendo Modules
import { ButtonsModule } from '@progress/kendo-angular-buttons';

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        ButtonsModule
    ],
  declarations: [ AppComponent ],
  bootstrap:    [ AppComponent ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

I have not changed any config files, nor have I attempted to actually use the Kendo Button. When I run the app, I get the following error:

```
Error: (SystemJS) XHR error (404 Not Found) loading http://localhost:49687/src/@progress/kendo-angular-buttons
```

I believe this is incorrect and "src" should be removed from this url. If I do this and use

```
http://localhost:49687/node_modules/@progress/kendo-angular-buttons/
```

instead, I get an HTTP Error 403.14 - Forbidden error, which merely means the contents of the directory cannot be listed in the browser.

So, my question: how do I get the url to not use "src"?

Comment: If I copy files to src/@progress/kendo-angular-buttons as an experiment,  I get the 403 error again. So now I'm really confused.

Answer (score 0):

Have you imported `@progress/kendo-angular-buttons` in your systemjs.config.js? like

```
packages: {
  '@progress/kendo-angular-buttons': {
    main: 'THEJSFILEOFKENDOANGULARBUTTONS.umd.js',
    defaultExtension: 'js'
  }
}
```

Comment: No, as I said I changed no config files. I don't see any *umd* files anyway. I did try this from another example but it didn't change any thing:   '@progress/kendo-angular-buttons': {
   main: './dist/npm/main.js', defaultExtension: 'js' },
   defaultExtension: 'js'
  },